# Flashing cursor when trying to boot from Windows 10 Bootable USB - many attempts to fix failed

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, usb, bootable-media

I've tried many different forums where questions have been asked about this and answered, but I can't seem to find something that works for me.

Recently I wiped and repartitioned my SSD (partition scheme: GPT) and did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 on the relevant partitions where I wanted it installed. My plan was to do this, and install Windows afterwards on a different partition. On Ubuntu, I downloaded the Windows 10 64-bit ISO from the Microsoft website, and formatted my USB.

I've tried many different ways to format the USB, both using DOS/MBR and GPT partitioning schemes and using NTFS and FAT32 formats; I've also tried both using the `dd` command in the terminal, and copy/pasting directly from the ISO when mounted. Finally, I've tried both with Virtualization Technology Off and On through BIOS, with USB Hard Drive at the top of the boot order, and, closest to success, enabling legacy devices.

It just seems to not work, no matter which way I try it. It skips when Legacy sources are disabled, and when I directly choose the device through legacy sources, it loads up and displays a flashing cursor, and nothing else. I am now admitting defeat and asking for help here. How do I fix this problem, assuming I just have Ubuntu installed?

I hope I've described my problem in enough detail. Please let me know if there are things I can be clearer on.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the methods [from here](https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/)? It might be simpler to use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately yeah, I have tried those methods. Does Rufus have support on Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that Rufus is Windows-only. It must be that something is wrong with the Windows ISO. Where did you get it and for which hardware architecture?

Comment: I got the Windows ISO from its [official page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO), for 64-bit architecture (my processor uses Intel's 64-bit instruction set)

Comment: Perhaps you should get it again.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, though I suspect that, if there has been no update to the ISO since I got it yesterday, it may make no difference. Thank you for the help :)